# Uploading big SQL dumps to Xeround MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, xeround

I have an SQL dumb of my MySQL DB. its around 33MB and after compressing the zip archive is around 6MB. Still its too big for upload. phpMyAdmin interface of Xeround wont let me import this big file.

How should I proceed ?

I am on a mac, what command-line tools can I use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the procedure described at http://xeround.com/developers/how-to-import-mysql-database-to-xeround-cloud-database/ to paralleliz the data imports for larger DB sizes.
Hope this helps!

Comment: You should paraphrase the procedure here.